# Tkinter: Can you see all bindings of a widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In my application I want to toggle between two states, and in each of the states I want -> don't want various keys bound.

Right now what I've done is that in my class I've created an attribute `self.bindings = []` and then I have a method to create bindings:

```
def _create_bindings(self):
    self.bind("<Button-1>", self._canvas_on_click)
    self.bindings.append("<Button-1>")
    self.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self._canvas_on_2click)
    self.bindings.append("<Double-Button-1>")
    self.bind("<<arrow>>", self._canvas_on_arrows)
    self.bindings.append("<<arrow>>")
    self.bind("<space>", lambda event: self._toggle_selected())
    self.bindings.append("<space>")
    self.bind("<Key>", self._canvas_on_key_press)
    self.bindings.append("<Key>")
    self.bind("<BackSpace>", lambda event: self._empty_cell())
    self.bindings.append("<BackSpace>")
    self.bind("<Escape>", self._esc)
    self.bindings.append("<Escape>")
```

and then to remove them:

```
def _remove_bindings(self):
    for b in self.bindings:
        self.unbind(b)
```

It's not terrible but it does lead to some duplication (see create function: create binding + add to list).

I could create a wrapper to combine these two steps, but regardless I still have an extra attribute to manage.

Is there a function which I can call which would provide me the same information as `self.bindings` above?

Comment: Read about [`bindtags(tagList=None)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.bindtags-method)

Comment: I did, it didn't do what I wanted. It returned >>> app.mainarea.bindtags()
('.!mainarea', 'Canvas', '.', 'all') not ("<Escape>", ....).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call the `bind` method without any parameters it will return a list of all events that you have bound for that widget. Your `_remove_bindings` could look like this:

```
def _remove_bindings(self):
    for event in self.bind():
       self.unbind(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove the bindings.

Altering the 'state' attribute of the e.g. Canvas, Button disables any bindings.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question. If you decided to use another approach  don't post this as answer.

Comment: My initial approach was predicated on the assumption that I had to explicitly delete and re-add the bindings. I wasn't aware of the impact of the state attribute, and using it greatly simplifies the code and logic. It is entirely possible that others googling this question also have the same misconception as I had, and that highlighting the fact that I did would provide value. 

The above doesn't answer the literal question posed but it does answer the implied: "How do I do ...." .